# How do I pass an item in a Vuex list to a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

So, I have a `Vuex` state that looks like so:

```
state: {
  keylist: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
  items: {
    key1: {title: "First Item"},
    key2: {title: "Second Item"},
    key3: {title: "Third Item"}
  }
}
```

And I have a list component, referenced from root like so:

```
<event-list :list="this.$store.state.keylist"></event-list>
```

The components is defined like so:

```
Vue.component('event-list', {
  template: "<ul><li v-for='key in list'>{{ key }}</li></ul>",
  props: {
    list: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
```

Now, this all displays the key just fine.

But, of course, what I really want to do is use a component on each item, found by it's key. And that's where I am stuck. I have an item component like so:

```
Vue.component('event-list-item', {
  template: "<h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>",
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
})
```

But I cannot figure out how to translate the `key` in the parent component into an `item` in the child component. This template barfs on the first curly brace:

```
<ul><li v-for='key in list'><event-list-item :item="this.$store.state.items.{{key}}"</li></ul>
```

And in any case, that doesn't *look* like the right solution! so What *is* the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the first thing that comes to mind is that's your nested item has no place to be inserted anyway. You might want to have a look at slots for nesting components like that:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Anyway, a few considerations:

In your use case you are better off having the list in the event list item and repeat just the element that you actually need, rather than retrieving it in a useless component that only wraps around another component. I mean:

```
Vue.component('event-list-item', {   template: "<li v-for="item in list"><h4>{{ item.title }}</h4></li>
```

The store is considered the single source of truth also because it should be easier to access it from the directly impacted components, sparing you from having to hand down multiple props for several layers. Like you are doing. This base is kinda brittle for deeply nested components.

Keep in mind that each component has a different scope and they don't share a thing that's not explicitly passed.

Comment: I did something like that originally, Gigi, but because my list is a list of keys in the original state, rather than a list of objects, I wanted to go this route; but I think you are saying that a better model would dispense with the key list, and just have a list of objects themselves. This would require more assembly on the server, but is doable.

Comment: You can try different routes:
Retrieve both the keylist and the items in the child component and repeat the single item:
<h4 v-for="key in keylist">{{$store.items[key]}}</h4>
Or you can try mapping the list (although it's very unwieldy) in the computed properties.
Finally you could refurbish the model as a list stored as object make little sense usually, and moving to an array that's easily sortable should be a nice shot for maintainability. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should access the state `items` fields like `key` :

```
   <ul><li v-for='key in list'><event-list-item :item='key' /></li></ul>
```

and in tht child component :

```
   template: "<h4>{{ store.state.items[item].title }}</h4>"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem of iterating through properties of `items` object. It will work the same way as iterating through an array.

```
<ul>
  <li 
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.title"
  >
    <event-list-item :item="item" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

For better practice, you can format data inside a getter, to assign keys and return a list that is ready for rendering so no additional logic is delegated to the component.

Note that `key` used in code example is for internal use of Vue, as it is a reserved [special attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) and is suggested to be present when using `v-for` loops.